# What does "decreases more slowly" mean mathematically with regard to distributions?

Tags: functions, terminology

In a paper I'm reading, the authors state that a certain distribution "*decreases more slowly than exponentially over a portion of the range*". What does this mean, mathematically?

Assuming $A$ is the domain and $p$ is the distribution function in question, does it mean that $p(x) \geq \mathbb e^{-x}$ for each $x \in E$, where $E \subset A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at "$f$ decreases more slowly than $g$.".

1. "$f$ decreases (...)" or: $f' < 0$
2. "(...) than $g$" or: $g$ decreases as well: $g' < 0$.
3. "*more slowly*": $|f'| < |g'|$

In other words we have
$$g'(t) < f'(t) < 0$$
for $t$ in said range.

Now if we have "exponentially" instead of a particular function, the author most likely refers to the general behaviour of $f$ compared to functions $g$ of exponential type, i.e. $g(t) = Ce^{at}$ where $C$ and $a$ are in reasonable (context-dependent) ranges.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you. :)

Comment: Didn't you mean $f'(t) < g'(t) < 0$ in the last line?

Comment: @AntonSchigur No, "more slowly" as in "closer to $0$". Note that $|f'|<|g'|$ and $f',g'<0$ implies $g'<f'<0$ already.